# Service providing a Subject observable doesn't receive notifications

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

EventSpinner component subscribes to icons provided by EventsService.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'event-spinner',
    template: `
<div class="col-xs-5">
    Test <i class="fa fa-2x" [ngClass]="{'fa-check': icon == 'ok', 'fa-spin': icon == 'loading', 'fa-spinner': icon == 'loading', 'fa-times': icon == 'error'}" id="spin"></i>
</div>
  `
})
export class EventSpinner implements OnInit {
    icon: string;

    constructor(public eventsService: EventsService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.eventsService.icons.subscribe((icon) => {
            let old = this.icon;
            this.icon = icon;
            console.log("this.icon = " + this.icon + " (was " + old + ")");
        });
    }

}
```

icons.next is called when a web service request using @angular/http.get state changes ("loading"/"ok"/"error"). however when this happens the class of the i tag doesn't get updated. any idea?

**EventsService.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class EventsService {
    icons: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    constructor(public http: Http) {
    }

    subscribe(): Observable<Event[]> {
        let url = (<any>window).__ext.API_URL + 'event/view';
        let obs;
        return Observable
            .create((o) => {
                obs = o;
                obs.next();
            })
            .flatMap(() => {
                this.icons.next("loading");
                console.log("executing request");
                return this.http.get(url)
            })
            .retryWhen(error => {
                this.icons.next("error");
                return error.delay(3000);
            })
            .map((response: Response) => {
                this.icons.next("ok");
                console.log("response received");
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log("pushing next");
                    obs.next();
                }, 1000);
                return (<any>response.json()).map(item => {
                    return item;
                });
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the console.log is displayed when an event is triggered?

Comment: What is `EventsService`?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier yes

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I attached the code of EventsService

Comment: Nothing that's obvious that would cause change detection to fail. Can you please try the suggestion from my answer and tell if the behavior changes?

Comment: I realize you already have your answer, but I am confused since you don't seem to be calling `EventService#subscribe` anywhere how you are getting any values at all...

Comment: @paulpdaniels It is called in another component. Does this influence change detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be caused by the implementation of `EventService` or might be an issue with `ngClass` but manually invoking change detection should work around the issue:

```
export class EventSpinner implements OnInit {
    icon: string;

    constructor(public eventsService: EventsService, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.eventsService.icons.subscribe((icon) => {
            let old = this.icon;
            this.icon = icon;
            console.log("this.icon = " + this.icon + " (was " + old + ")");
            this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This works... Can you guess why changes aren't automatically detected? Is it a bug or something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be a bug in Angular or zone. It might be something with your project setup. For example the wrong version of RxJS or some polyfills applied the wrong way. I don't have much knowledge here though because I'm only using Dart.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
new Observable(...);
```

and

```
new BehaviorSubject(...);
```

instead of the static

```
X.create();
```

fixed all my issues.